# Run a CMake-generated INSTALL.vcxproj on Windows via command line only?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, command-line, cmake

I have a C++ program that I'm trying to build and deploy on AppVeyor (thus, I have no GUI tools available).  The dependencies of my project each use CMake for their build systems, and CMake (by default) generates Visual Studio project files on Windows.

One of the generated project files is named `INSTALL.vcxproj`, which presumably installs the dependency somewhere more or less standard.  **How can I execute the build process of `INSTALL.vcxproj` using only the command line?**

**Note:** I am not married to Visual Studio project files.  If it's more convenient to just use another generator, that's fine too (if you can explain to me how).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To invoke the building of a specific target, use the `--target` option of [cmake --build](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/manual/cmake.1.html), i.e. in your case the command will look like `cmake --build (YOUR_BUILD_FOLDER) --config Release --target install`. Of course you need to set up your compiler environment using `vcvarsall.bat`. You can use this command with other generators as well (note, that `--config` option is for multi-configuration tools only, MSVS is one of them).

Comment: Also note if you're installing to a directory that requires elevated privileges you must run the `Visual Studio Command Prompt` as Administrator.

Answer (score 5):

cmake on windows (with Visual studio) will generate severial files:

1. 1.sln
2. a.vcxproj
3. b.vcxproj
4. INSTALL.vxcproj

To build, just open the `Visual Studio Command Prompt` and run:

```
msbuild b.vcxproj
```

If `a.vcxproj` is reference by `b`, it will be built automatically.

To install, open `Visual Studio Command Prompt` **as administrator**, and run:

```
msbuild INSTALL.vcxproj
```

These are equivalent to linux:

```
make
make install
```