# io2d error for command msbuild INSTALL.vcxproj error

Tags: cmake, vcpkg

I'm trying to install io2d in order to build the RoutePlanning Project provided in this link:

https://github.com/udacity/CppND-Route-Planning-Project
However when entering the command:

```
msbuild INSTALL.vcxproj
```

I get this error at the end:
[image]

Comment: The title is misleading: the error comes not from `io2d` project, but from the other projects which uses io2d. "I'm trying to install io2d in order to ..." - So, have you installed `io2d` or not? If not, and your search about *installing CMake project* gives you (for some reasons) no results, then see that question and its answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33291856/run-a-cmake-generated-install-vcxproj-on-windows-via-command-line-only.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I'm not sure the error comes from other projects, I have followed the instructions on installing io2d, I have the .sln file but not sure when to go from there, I opened the io2d.sln project file but not sure how to install it, I run the command "make install" but I get an error *** No rule to make target `install'. Stop.

Comment: "I'm not sure the error comes from other projects" - You follow the guide for RoutePlanning project, and the command for build this project - `cmake ..` - cause the error. That mean you got the error while building RoutePlanning project. As for installing `io2d` from the `.sln` file, have you read the answers from the reference from my previous comment? It doesn't contain `make install` suggestion.

Comment: @Tsyvarev so If I understand you correctly, having the io2d.sln means it's been installed right? or should I run msbuild Install.vcxproj?

Comment: No, just having `.sln` file doesn't mean the project is installed. You need to build `INSTALL.vcxproj` file. You may use `msbuild` command for this purpose.

Comment: @Tsyvarev sorry to bother, but when I run "CMake .." I got these errors (shown in question post), what is exactly causing it?!

Comment: Seems you need to install Cairo and GraphicsMagic before building the project.

Comment: Please, stop using screenshots for *textual* information: this only makes harder to help you. Also note, that "chameleon" questions (the questions, which content changes drastically) are not well-received on Stack Overflow.